# How to find sequence formula

Tags: sequence, wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I am looking for a sequence formula. The sequence is {1,5,18, 56,160,432}.

I tried using wolframs mathematica - FindSequenceFunction and FindGeneratingFunction. First one did not even give me a function, second one gave me 1-n/(1-2n)^3 which i dont see how this can be right. Maybe I dont understand mathematica properly. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

```
https://oeis.org/
```

and enter

```
1,5,18,56,160,432
```

and tap Search

and in a fraction of a second it finds that you are not the first person looking at that sequence, that sequence has actually shown up in two different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn[x_] := Evaluate[
  FindGeneratingFunction[{1, 5, 18, 56, 160, 432}, x]]

Series[fn[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

> 1 + 5 x + 18 x^2 + 56 x^3 + 160 x^4 + 432 x^5 + O[x]^6

`FindSequenceFunction` needs another couple of terms before it nails it

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 5, 18, 56, 160, 432, 1120, 2816}, n]
```

> 2^(-3 + n) n (3 + n)

Same as OEIS [A001793](https://oeis.org/A001793)